# Facebook API retrieving FriendList Object and subsequently friends from each friendlist

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph (rest) API, and I'd like to retrieve facebook FriendList object of a certain user, and then I'd need to retrieve friends from a particular FriendList. I have looked into [facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/) but I don't understand what is FRIENDLIST_ID and how am I suppose to know the ID. Please if someone has done it before please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

FRIENDLIST_ID/members returns the members.